# Obtain HTML String with Android API 23

Tags: java, android

I am working on project to get html source code in a string using dom parser to get source code of a page.

I want to implement the same in android, what will be the approach to get source code of webpage by calling a url in android API 23 ANDROID.

What would be the best approach to do that in android ?

Comment: Make standard http get request in Android. You may use volley for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
class GetWebPage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            doRequest();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public void doRequest() {
        String link = "http://www.google.com";
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            String webPage = "",data="";

            while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null){
                webPage += data + "\n";
            }
            Log.d("goog",webPage);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

In onCreate of your actvity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new GetWebPage().execute();
    }
```

and now check the logcat. With tag goog
Don't forget to add the internet permission in the AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I implemented the code, Android Studio forcing me to put the try / catch block, and do not know why, always executes the catch block :(

Comment: catch(Exception ex) { ex.printstacktrace();} see logs. Give me logs.

Comment: did it work? let me know if you are facing any issues

Comment: YES ! I implemented this solution and it works really well, I think the other, however, were correct ... Many Thanks: D

Comment: If I turn the "doRequest ()" in String can usually retrieve it from another class?

Comment: Yes. You can. Read a bit about AsyncTask. http calls on activity thread will cause a crash.
Accept the answer if it has solved your problem.

Comment: You do me a practical example of how to call this method? I tried to call him back but I do not get anything in response

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this java library [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), so you can get the html of a web page like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
```

However you should call it from an `doRequest` of an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to avoid to block the user interface during the call.

and remember to add to the Android manifest file the:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

---

Otherwise there are a lot of libraries to manage this kind of http calls asynchonously on Android over the web. A famous one is the [Android Asynchronous Http Client](https://loopj.com/android-async-http/) (you should always remember the android manifest entry).